# pywinauto print_control_identifiers() raises KeyError: None or _ctypes.COMError

Tags: automation, win32com, pywinauto

I have an issue with pywinauto, using the print_control_identifiers() function. I want to view the tree of elements in the current window, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\formation_uploading__tranco\app\tranco.py", line 170, in run_process
    self.process()
  File "C:\formation_uploading__tranco\app\tranco.py", line 73, in process
    window.print_control_identifiers()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 624, in print_control_identifiers
    ctrl_names = findbestmatch.get_control_names(ctrl, all_ctrls, txt_ctrls)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 320, in get_control_names
    non_text_names = get_non_text_control_name(control, allcontrols, textcontrols)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 219, in get_non_text_control_name
    ctrl_r = ctrl.rectangle()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 367, in rectangle
    return self.element_info.rectangle
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py", line 326, in rectangle
    bound_rect = self._element.CurrentBoundingRectangle
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147220991, 'An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My code is:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re="1С:Предприятие - АТК:Управление грузоперевозками")
window = app.window(title_re="1С:Предприятие - АТК:Управление грузоперевозками")
window.set_focus()
button_5 = window.child_window(title="Разобрать", control_type="Button")
button_5.click_input()
button_6 = window.child_window(title="Перечни", control_type="TabItem")
button_6.click_input()
window.print_control_identifiers()
```

button_5 and button_6 executed correctly

If I add depth in print_control_identifiers(depth=3), I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\formation_uploading__tranco\app\tranco.py", line 170, in run_process
    self.process()
  File "C:\formation_uploading__tranco\app\tranco.py", line 73, in process
    window.print_control_identifiers(depth=3)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 616, in print_control_identifiers
    all_ctrls = [this_ctrl, ] + this_ctrl.descendants()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 493, in descendants
    return [self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(element_info) for element_info in desc_elements]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 493, in <listcomp>
    return [self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(element_info) for element_info in desc_elements]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uia_controls.py", line 1102, in __init__
    if not self.children() and self.element_info.handle is not None:
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 471, in children
    return [self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(element_info) for element_info in child_elements]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 471, in <listcomp>
    return [self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(element_info) for element_info in child_elements]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 186, in __new__
    return super(UIAWrapper, cls)._create_wrapper(cls, element_info, UIAWrapper)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 126, in _create_wrapper
    new_class = cls_spec.find_wrapper(element_info)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 160, in find_wrapper
    wrapper_match = UiaMeta.control_type_to_cls[element.control_type]
KeyError: None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I also added window.set_focus(), some sleeps for 2-30 seconds, added a window = app.window(title_re="") many times, still got nothing. window.wait('ready', timeout=10) as well. Created a new application after executing these buttons, tried to call the tree already in it, still same errors.

Any ideas how to investigate/what can be done to debug it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of pywinauto is installed in your environment?

The last sources on the [Github repo](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) have a try-except block for `KeyError` around the line 160 in the `uiawrapper.py` file, which is mentioned in your traceback.

You can try to install the newest pywinauto from Github directly

`pip install git+https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto`

in case you use the pip package manager.